# How do I fix this seg fault?

Tags: c

I cannot find what is causing my segfault on line 151. I don't understand why it is segfaulting. I have to add up the time a customer enters the line plus 5 * the number of items at checkout + 30 for the cashier.

stdin

Sample Input

2

5

10 1 STEVEN 12

12 6 AHMAD 8

13 1 JENNY 40

22 6 JERMAINE 39

100000 12 AMALIA 53

6

100 1 A 100

200 2 B 99

300 3 C 98

400 4 D 97

500 5 E 96

600 6 F 95

Sample Output

STEVEN from line 1 checks out at time 100.

AHMAD from line 6 checks out at time 170.

JERMAINE from line 6 checks out at time 395.

JENNY from line 1 checks out at time 625.

AMALIA from line 12 checks out at time 100295.

A from line 1 checks out at time 630.

F from line 6 checks out at time 1135.

E from line 5 checks out at time 1645.

D from line 4 checks out at time 2160.

C from line 3 checks out at time 2680.

B from line 2 checks out at time 3205.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

// customer record
typedef char customerName[9];

typedef struct customer {
    customerName name;                  // 1-9 upper case letters
    int lineNumber;                     // line number customer gets on
    int time;                           // arrival time at line
    int numberItems;                    // number of items customer has
} customer;

// [singly linked] queue element
typedef customer *qitem;

typedef struct node {
    qitem data;                         // pointer to actual data
    struct node *next;                  // forward pointer to next item
} node;

// queue definition (singly linked list)
// NOTE:
typedef struct queue {
    node *front;                        // pointer to first node in list ie front of line with cashier
} queue;

// qinit -- initialize/reset queue
void qinit(queue *q)
{
    q->front = NULL;
}

// qempty -- returns 1 if empty or 0 if false
int qempty(queue *q)
{
    return (q->front == NULL);
}

// enqueue -- append element to end of queue
void enqueue(queue *q, qitem data)
{
    node *newnode;
    node *prev;

    newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->data = data;

    // find the back of the queue with only a front pointer
    prev = NULL;
    for (node *cur = q->front;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        prev = cur;

    // append to tail of list
    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = newnode;

    // add to end of empty list
    else
        q->front = newnode;

}

// dequeue -- dequeue from the front of the queue
qitem dequeue(queue *q)
{
    node *curnode;
    qitem data;

    do {
        curnode = q->front;

        if (curnode == NULL) {
            data = NULL;
            break;
        }

        // get node's data value (e.g. pointer to customer struct)
        data = curnode->data;

        // release the node's storage back to the heap
        free(curnode);
    } while (0);

    return data;
}

// qfront -- peek at front of queue
qitem qfront(queue *q)
{
    node *curnode;
    qitem data;

    curnode = q->front;
    if (curnode != NULL)
        data = curnode->data;
    else
        data = NULL;

    return data;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int testCases = 0;
    scanf("%d", &testCases);

    if(testCases > 0 && testCases <= 25){//shortcircuiting???

    while (testCases--){

        int numCustomers;
        scanf("%d", &numCustomers);

        if(numCustomers < 0 || numCustomers > 11){
            return 0;
        }

        queue* customerArray = (queue*) malloc(sizeof(queue) * 12);

        for ( int i = 0; i < numCustomers; i++){
            qinit(customerArray);// starting new queue

            customer* newCustomer = (customer*) malloc(sizeof(customer));

            scanf("%d", &(newCustomer->time));
            scanf("%d", &(newCustomer->lineNumber));
            scanf("%s", newCustomer->name);
            scanf("%d", &(newCustomer->numberItems));
            enqueue(&customerArray[newCustomer->lineNumber - 1], newCustomer);
        }


        int totalTime = INT_MAX;

        for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
        {
        customer* frontCustomer = qfront(&customerArray[i]);

         if(totalTime < frontCustomer->time)
            {
                totalTime = frontCustomer->time;
            }

         }

       while(numCustomers--) {

        int customerToCheckOutLine = 0; int minNumberOfItems = INT_MAX;

        for( int j=11 ; j>=0; j--){

            customer* frontCustomer = qfront(&customerArray[j]);

            if(frontCustomer->time <= totalTime)
            {
                if(frontCustomer->numberItems < minNumberOfItems)
                {
                    customerToCheckOutLine = frontCustomer->lineNumber;
                    minNumberOfItems = frontCustomer->numberItems;
                }

            }
            free(frontCustomer);
        }


        customer* customerToCheckOut = qfront(&customerArray[customerToCheckOutLine -1 ]);
        totalTime += 30;
        totalTime += (customerToCheckOut->numberItems) * 5;
           dequeue(&customerArray[customerToCheckOutLine - 1]);
       }
        free(customerArray);

    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code for a tiny bit of functionality. This could be compacted to 40 lines or so. (not counting the empty lines)

Comment: Its my second program. So if you would like to teach me Obi Wan I am all ears.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
    qinit(customerArray);// starting new queue
```

Is wrong, it should probably init customerArray+i.

but this line is odd:

```
    enqueue(&customerArray[newCustomer->lineNumber - 1], newCustomer);
```

since it could use a q that hasn't been init'd, and since lineNumber isn't value checked, could be just about anything.

But because of one or both of the above, this line:

```
customer       *frontCustomer = qfront(&customerArray[i]);
```

Can return NULL; but without checking, you go on to use frontCustomer without checking, so your program SEGV's.

Comment: What do you mean checking? like if(frontCustomer == NULL){ return 0};   ?

Comment: How does the enqueue line cause a segfault? it read enqueue the customers line number -1 to account for 0-11 lines. customer array is the queue and it queues new customer.  What is value checked? the value of line number is scanned in just two lines before how can it be anything?

Comment: Yes, check for NULL, because you cannot write to, or read from, 0.  The customerArray entry for index newCustomer->lineNumber -1 may not have been initialized by qinit, thus the front pointer likely contains random numbers.

Comment: I got it to complie with no crashes. I have to figure how to print this madness to the screen now